# COMException "Library not registered." while using System.DirectoryServices

Tags: com, .net-2.0, active-directory

I have only just started received the following error in my windows forms application under .NET 2 framework on windows 2000 when using `System.DirectoryServices`.

```
    {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException}
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: {"Library not registered."}
_className: Nothing
_COMPlusExceptionCode: -532459699
_data: Nothing
_dynamicMethods: Nothing
_exceptionMethod: Nothing
_exceptionMethodString: Nothing
_helpURL: Nothing
_HResult: -2147319779
_innerException: Nothing
_message: "Library not registered."
_remoteStackIndex: 0
_remoteStackTraceString: Nothing
_source: Nothing
_stackTrace: {System.Array}
_stackTraceString: Nothing
_xcode: -532459699
_xptrs: 0
Source: "System.DirectoryServices"
StackTrace: "   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) 
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll()
```

I have re-installed the framework and re-registered `activeds.dll` however this has not resolved the issue. I am guessing I need to find another dll and re-register it however it is not clear which dll this would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having used [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to have a quick peak at the Directory Services code, it looks like your Active Directory Service Interfaces installation might be kaput.

You can download version 2.5 from [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749949.aspx) although I'm not sure if it's the latest version or if it works with Windows 2000.