# Don't understand the link between System.DirectoryServices and activeds.tlb

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, directoryservices

I wrote a VB.NET 4 application using the namespace

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
```

Worked perfectly in Windows Seven and Server 2012. I got stuck with a VM running with Server 2008, this error occured :

```
Library not registered
```

With a stacktrace similar to the one of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270/comexception-library-not-registered-while-using-system-directoryservices) :

```
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) 
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
at [...]
```

After a long search, I finally solved my problem with this single line :

```
C:\Windows\REGTLIB.EXE activeds.tlb
```

I found and did it as an attempt of last resort... Why this worked, and, for further issues, how to find the related tlb file by myself ?

Comment: It is a workaround for registry corruption, it puts the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib\{97d25db0-0363-11cf-abc4-02608c9e7553} registry key back.  Originally written by the Windows installer.  Do keep in mind that such corruption is rarely an isolated incident, so you might well have more trouble with that machine.  Nuke from orbit, only way to be sure.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks. You mean REGTLIB is just designed as a workaround tool ?

Comment: No, it was meant as an install tool.  Discontinued a long time ago but still found back on *some* machines, the .NET Framework installer uses it.

Comment: If this kind of error reproduces again with another namespace, is there a way to found the relevant tlb to register ?

Comment: Chicken-and-egg problem of course.   You'd know the TLB name from the registry key.  But if it is missing then you can't know the TLB name.  You'd have to look at the registry of another machine that also has the component installed but doesn't have a corrupted registry.  After which you'd certainly consider swapping machines because registry corruption is a nasty problem.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for the help. I hope this question will be useful for other developers.